# Unable to create custom facebook object

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph

I'm making a Facebook canvas application, and I want give some of the objects there "Facebook presence" - I want to allow users to comment on them and to like and share them via Facebook.

I understand I need to do it via OpenGraph. So I created an object type on my OpenGraph and named it `item`. I've tried to create an instance of `item` with the following `POST` request:

url:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/https://graph.facebook.com/me/objects/ilender_local-test:item
```

body:

```
method=POST&object=%7B%22type%22%3A%22%5C%22ilender_local-test%3Aitem%5C%22%22%2C%22title%22%3A%22My+First+Item%22%7D&access_token=...
```

The `access_token`, ofcourse, is the access token for my app.

Now, the result I get is a simple JSON `false` - no error message - but I assume I failed since when I succeed in creating an object on Facebook I usually get the id of the newly created object.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

My stupidity knows no end. `https://graph.facebook.com/https://graph.facebook.com`? What was I thinking...